# MKL02Z32xxx4 (FRDM-KL02Z Board) Timer overflow interrupt not firing

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, nxp-microcontroller

I never get into the TPM0_IRQHandler() it's supposed to call. However, all of the register seem to be set, even the Timer Overflow Flag register when the timer actually overflows. So appears it just doesn't know where the IRQ handler is located, but the vector table looks okay.

I then tried an SDK example and it shows the same behavior. Pretty confident it isn't my code now. Not sure where else to look on why this might not be working.

```
void initTimer()
{
    tpm_config_t tpmConfig;
    TPM_GetDefaultConfig(&tpmConfig);
    tpmConfig.prescale = kTPM_Prescale_Divide_128;

    NVIC_SetPriority(TPM0_IRQn, 3);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TPM0_IRQn);

    TPM_Init(TPM0, &tpmConfig);

    uint32_t tpmClock = TPM_SOURCE_CLOCK;
    uint32_t timerPeriod = USEC_TO_COUNT(1000U, tpmClock) / 128; // 1ms

    TPM_EnableInterrupts(TPM0, kTPM_TimeOverflowInterruptEnable);

    TPM_SetTimerPeriod(TPM0, timerPeriod);
    TPM_StartTimer(TPM0, kTPM_SystemClock);
}

volatile uint32_t elapsedTime = 0;

void TPM0_IRQHandler()
{
    TPM_ClearStatusFlags(TPM0, kTPM_TimeOverflowFlag);
    elapsedTime++;

    printf("Elapsed time: %d\n", elapsedTime);

    if (elapsedTime >= 1000) // 1 ms has passed
    {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        // Toggle the LED_RED GPIO here
        // Example code assuming GPIO is already configured:
        GPIO_PortToggle(BOARD_INITPINS_LED_RED_GPIO, 1u << BOARD_INITPINS_LED_RED_PIN);
    }
}
```

Should be a pretty straightforward setup, any advice would be appreciated. I'm not even sure what else to check.

I'm using MCUXpresso (latest)

Comment: How are you determining that the ISR is not called? Are you running in the debugger and setting a breakpoint? On many platforms, calling things like `printf()` in an ISR is a terrible idea.

Comment: I tried a couple of things. Flipping a GPIO, print, breakpoint. My buddy is developing on an openSDA board and his breakpoints worked in the ISR so assumed it would work. Also, the TOF flag isn't getting cleared when I call it in the ISR.

If I poll the TOF flag from main it hits and I can clear it, doesn't seem to happen when I move the code to ISR.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your platform, but is there a global "interrupt enable" bit in a register that needs to be set? Are there any other interrupt sources you could test to see if they work?

Comment: The only thing I see is an NVIC (Nested Vector Interrupt Controller) register which has the value set to enable the interrupt I want to use. The thing is their SDK example project using the same interrupt also doesn't work. I'm going to assume their code is good. Think it's something in my setup. Like a linker issue or something.

Comment: Does your interrupt vector table contain `TPM0_IRQHandler` in the expected place? Or a stub function that calls it?

Comment: Yes it's in the correct place. I'm thinking there is an issue with the linker script placing the table in the right place. Not sure how to check this...I'm going to look in this direction.

Comment: The linker script has the TPM0_IRQHandler at 0x88c, and during debug the address in the vector array is 0x88d. Sounds about right, not sure how to interpret the 1 byte difference. Does it start 1 byte after the pointer or something? 

I'm completely lost on this. I'm out of ideas. Their example project with TPM0 timer overflow interrupt also isn't working. Think I'll just throw it against the wall.